# Let $f$ be holomorphic in $G$. Show that $N := \{ z\in G : D^vf(z)=0$ for all $v\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic in $G$. Then $N := \{ z\in G : D^vf(z)=0$ for all $v\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is closed.

This is a step for proving Identity Theorem in multivariable case.

The claim in the book is that "Because all derivatives $D^v(f)$ are continuous, $N$ is closed." which I can't completely comprehend.

[image: The page of the book from Google Book Preview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $\nu\in\mathbb N$, since $D^\mu f$ is continuous, the set of its zeros is a closed set. Since $N=\bigcap_{\nu\in\mathbb N}\{z\in G\mid D^\mu f(z)=0\}$, $N$ is closed too.

Comment: Oh yes I should have thought of this! Thanks a lot.